# Meteor accounts invite new users

Tags: meteor, accounts

I have my site configured to login with email/password (no user name).

I have login, forgot password, and password reset pages working as expected, largely based off of [this guide](http://blog.benmcmahen.com/post/41741539120/building-a-customized-accounts-ui-for-meteor) and a **lot** of poking around. I'm at a bit of a loss looking for a more comprehensive or "advanced" guide for controlling user account behavior.

Currently, a registered user can "invite" another user by simply putting in their email address. This person receives an email which brings them to the login screen, but since there is no password set yet, this person must

1. Click on the forgot password link
2. Input their email
3. Follow the link from the reset email and set their password.

I'm trying to work out how I would get the initial invite email to land the person on a "set password" page.

Even a link to the relevant material is greatly appreciated! I have a feeling I may just be searching for the wrong things.

Comment: Why not bring them to a signup page?

Comment: @AlexPan They've already been registered so signup isn't necessary. For ease of use, I'd want them to have a token that allows them to set their password without entering their email address again, much like the reset password functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done it myself, but off top of my head, as an idea (requires Iron-Router (`$ meteor add iron:router`)):

1) Send a link to an invited user with the query in the link that equals this user's email (q=email@address.com).
2) Use Iron Router to fetch that query (this.params.query using, perhaps, [onBeforeAction method](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#using-hooks)).
3) Put the query into a Session.
4) Within Template.*myTemplate*.helpers() create a new helper that will display the session.
5) Inside your template: `<input type="text" name="user_email_from_session" value="{{helper}}">`

Hopefully my approach is not too newbie, but even if so, maybe it will serve you as an anti-inspiration :)

Comment: This is probably the right direction at least. I certainly don't want to use the email address in the param string - the password reset currently uses a generated key. This keeps people from "hacking" the system.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor calls "invite" emails "enrollment" emails.

1) Create a new user on the server (doesn't need a password set).

2) Call `Accounts.sendEnrollmentEmail(userId)` on the server.

3) User receives an email with a link to set their initial password.

Docs: http://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-sendEnrollmentEmail